# SQLException Access denied for user 'ronal'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, database, hibernate

I am trying to connect database with application. Properties but I receive access denied error

here is my applicationproperties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employeemanager
spring.datasource.name=root
spring.datasource.password=1234
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

but on the error it is not saying 'root'@'localhost' it is saying 'ronal'@'localhost' ronal is my account name on this pc

I tried to connect with mysql database but I receive this error "java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'ronal'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

Answer (score 1):

It's `spring.datasource.username` not `spring.datasource.name`; change to

```
spring.datasource.username=root
```

And I think you also need

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

Comment: yes thank you it is the solution of problem maybe I should have been a bit more careful :)